# Handle multiple user controls inside the same WinForm window

Tags: c#

I am using the code below for creating 4 same usercontrols.

```
 vari = 0;
 for(int a =0;a<=3;a++)
 {
    i = i + 100;
    var control = new XtraUserControl1();
    control.Location = new Point(0, i);
    this.Controls.Add(control);
 }
```

How can i change example textbox text from Second control?

Comment: `How can i change example textbox text` what textbox text??? and what does that have to do with the title?

Comment: If `XtraUserControl1` is a custom user control that contains a textbox, and you want to be able to access that textbox from outside the control, you need to expose the textbox as a public property. Is this where you are having trouble? Perhaps if you posted the source code that defines the textbox, the question would be clearer.

Comment: It is just a single user control with a textbox inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allthogh that loop is not optimal and this can be solved better, here is a working version:

```
 var i = 0;
 for(int a =0;a<=3;a++)
 {
    i = i + 100;
    var control = new XtraUserControl1();
    control.Text = a == 1 ? "control 2 text" : "other controls text"
    control.Location = new Point(0, i);
    this.Controls.Add(control);
 }
```

or:

```
 var i = 0;
 for(int a =0;a<=3;a++)
 {
    i = i + 100;
    var control = new XtraUserControl1();
    switch (a)
    {
       case 1:
           control.Text = "control 2 text"
           break;
       default:
           control.Text = "other controls text"
           break;
       // you can add cases for other textboxes here 
    }
    control.Location = new Point(0, i);
    this.Controls.Add(control);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `XtraUserControl1` is a `UserControl` containing a text box `textBox1`, you can expose the text of this text box through a property. In the UserControl's code, write

```
public string Text1
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Now, you can access it like this

```
var control = new XtraUserControl1();
control.Location = new Point(0, i);
control.Text1 = "some text";
```

But choose a better name for the property than I did, describing the purpose of the field, like `Description`, `FirstName`, `Password` etc.